# Android Kitkat material issue: transparency not working

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I've been developing on Android 6 and did not see any problems, until I tested my app on Kitkat - support AppBarLayout went completely blank:

[image]

But interestingly enough, it is not blank - it is white on white - all menu items are working, including tabs. Clue to problem is highlighted on the list - rating stars' background is white instead of transparent. I assume AppBarLayout's transparent overlays are rendered white thus making primary color covered.

Here is another image of the BottomSheet:

[image]

Area that should be transparent is white!

The question is: how can I make it work?

P.S.: activity_main.:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/sto_item_cell_color"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/mainpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: are you using AppCompatActivity ??

Comment: of course! support libs 23.2.1